# Saving multiple preferences of a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to be able to save a user's preferences and I was wondering if I am on the right track.

Following example:

Tables

- User: has_many preferences
- Preference: belongs_to users, has_many pancakes, has_many icecreams
- Pancake: belongs_to preference
- Icecream: belongs_to preference

The tables have following content:

- User: name, email, telephone, ...
- Preference: user_id, pancake_id, icecream_id
- Pancake: name (i.e whipcream)
- Icecream: name (i.e strawberry)

Now, after a user creates his regular profile (name, email, sex, phonenumber, ..)
I want to redirect them to a page that makes them fill in their food preferences.

A user **can like multiple kinds of icecreams**.

Am I using the correct logic in order for a user to fill in their preferences?

Is there any better way I can achieve this goal of saving user preferences?

The way I am doing it now should result in something like this >>

Preferences

id, user_id, pancake_id, icecream_id

1, 2, [1,2], [3,5,7,2]

Is this efficient?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think we may modify the schema like this:

[image]

- `User` has many `Preference`
- `Preference` has many `Pancake` through `PreferencePancake`, so `PreferencePancake` is the joined table of `Preference` and `Pancake`
- `Preference` has many `Icecream` through `PreferenceIcecream`, so `PreferenceIcecream` is the joined table of `Preference` and `Icecream`

Why do I suggest this?

- A `Pancake` and `Icecream` are existing without caring about `Preference`
- The relation is more natural, and flexible for changing between `Preference` and `Pancake`/`Icecream`. Because a `User` can like many `Pancake` and `Icescream` as his preference. Btw a `Icescream` or a `Pancake` may be liked by many users.

Then, the definition of models is clear:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :preferences
end

class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :preference_pancakes
  has_many :preference_icescreams

  has_many :pancakes, through: :preference_pancakes
  has_many :icescreams, through: :preference_icescreams
end

class Pancake < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :preference_pancakes
end

class Icecream < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :preference_icescreams
end

class PreferencePancake < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :preference
  belongs_to :pancake
end

class PreferenceIcecream < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :preference
  belongs_to :icescream
end
```

Comment: Thank you,
In this case my preferencepancake table would have only 3 fields, right?
ID, user_id, pancake_id
And if I would want to get all the pancakes the user likes I can do
Preferencepancake.where(user_id: current_user) ?

Comment: @MartijnKerckhaert: Yes, to get all `pancakes` you may query `Pancake.joins(:reference_pancake).where(preference_pancakes: {user_id: current_user.id})`

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe use something simpler - has many through associations to model your reality.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :preferedicecreams
  has_many :icecreams, through: :preferedicecreams
end

class PreferedIcecream < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :icecream
end

class Icecream < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :preferedicereams
  has_many :users, through: :preferedicereams
end
```

And same for pancakes..